# Conditionally color bars in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts

I am trying to build a stacked chart using three variables but I am having trouble with representing the data.

Here is what the data looks like

| local manager | bins | sum by bins |
| --- | --- | --- |
| yes | (0.01,0.09] | 109 |
| no | (0.01,0.09] | 109 |
| yes | (0.01,0.09] | 109 |
| yes | (0.01,0.09] | 109 |
| no | (0.89,0.99] | 56 |
| no | (0.89,0.99] | 56 |
| no | (0.99,1] | 45 |
| yes | (0.69,0.79] | 33 |
| yes | (0.69,0.79] | 33 |

I want the bars to have the height of y-axis and be colored if local manager is yes/no/mixed, but I don't really know how to do that. For example the color of (0.01,0.09] bar would be orange since it has both yes and no.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you also post the ggplot code you already tried? That way we can build off of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that generates the desired plot. The main trick is to code the "local manager" column into the desired categories: "yes", "no", "mixed" using `summarise`. In this example `df` is your dataframe, except I shortened the name of "sum by bins" column to simply "sum".

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df |>
  # Group by bins
  group_by(bins) |>
  # Summarise to get yes, no, mixed classes
  summarise(n = length(unique(localmanager)),
            class = ifelse(n == 1, unique(localmanager), "mixed"),
            y = unique(sum)) |>
  # ggplot
  ggplot(aes(x = bins, 
             y = y,
             fill = class)) +
  # columns plot
  geom_col() +
  # Change fill colors according to class values
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("mixed" = "orange",
                               "no" = "firebrick3",
                               "yes" = "forestgreen"))
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Hi, what if instead of 'mixed' I want bars to be stacked?  For example (0.01,0.09] should have stacked bars(colored in two colors) since it has both yes and no.

Comment: I guess you could use directly `ggplot` on `df`, setting `fill = localmanager` and creating `geom_col(position = "stack")`.